Unit Test with Mock for a Response Object
I have a service; this service uses Response (IResponse) Object, this is the handler of service:
    [LogRequestDto]
    [LogResponseDto]
    [RequiresAnyRole(Roles.EventWrite, Roles.EventAdmin)]
    public NewEventResponse Post(NewEvent request)
    {
        long eventId;
        try
        {
          ......
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, 
                HttpErrorCodes.InternalServerError.ToString(), HttpErrorMessages.InternalServerError);
        }
        
        if (Response == null) 
            throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                HttpErrorCodes.NotGenerateResponse.ToString(), HttpErrorMessages.NotGenerateResponse);
        
        .......

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
        
        return new NewEventResponse
        {
            EventId = eventId,
            .......
        };
    }

and this is my unit test:
[Test, Order(1)]
    public void NewEventTest_Successful()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new NewEvent
        {
            ...        };
        
        var eventData = new EventData().PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(request);
        var eventId = new Random().NextInt64();
        
        var eventManagerMock = new Mock<IEventManager>();

        var requestContextMock = new Mock<RequestContext>();
        var requestMock = new Mock<IRequest>();

        eventManagerMock.Setup(x => x.CreateNewEvent(
            It.Is<EventData>(y => 
                y.Id.Equals(eventData.Id) &&
                ...........
                y.Metadata.Zip(eventData.Metadata, (metaY, metaR) => 
                    metaY.Key == metaR.Key &&
                    metaY.Value == metaR.Value).All(result => result)
                )
        )).Returns(eventId)
        .Verifiable("IEventManager.CreateNewEvent was not invoked.");
        
        BaseAppHost.Container.Register(eventManagerMock.Object);
        BaseAppHost.Container.Register(requestContextMock.Object);
        BaseAppHost.Container.Register(requestMock.Object);
        
        var service = BaseAppHost.Container.Resolve<EventServices>();
        
        // Act
        var response = service.Post(request);

        // Assert
        eventManagerMock.Verify();
        
    }

But in the run, in the code segment:
if (Response == null) 
            throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
                HttpErrorCodes.NotGenerateResponse.ToString(), HttpErrorMessages.NotGenerateResponse);

The response object is always null and does not establish a mocked value. Do they have any idea of a solution to this problem?

Consider writing an interface for anything you are unit testing.

Post(NewEvent request) this is probably not the most optimal method name - consider an actual name of purpose and [HttpPost]] attribute decorator use

FWIW we IMHO really cannot weigh in on if (Response == null) since creation of that response object is NOT in the presented  code here

Have you tried It.IsAny
eventManagerMock.Setup(x => x.CreateNewEvent(
It.IsAny()
)).Returns(eventId)

I have managed to solve the problem I was having, the solution is as follows:

    [Test, Order(1)]
    public void NewEventTest_Successful()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new NewEvent
        {...};
        
        var eventData = new EventData().PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(request);
        var eventId = new Random().Next();
        
        var eventManagerMock = new Mock<IEventManager>();
        var responseMock = new Mock<IResponse>();
        var requestMock = new Mock<IRequest>();

        requestMock.Setup(x => x.Response)
            .Returns(responseMock.Object)
            .Verifiable("IRequest.Response was not invoked.");

        eventManagerMock.Setup(x => x.CreateNewEvent(
            It.Is<EventData>(y => ..........)
        )).Returns(eventId)
        .Verifiable("IEventManager.CreateNewEvent was not invoked.");
        
        BaseAppHost.Container.Register(eventManagerMock.Object);
        BaseAppHost.Container.Register(requestMock.Object);
        
        var service = BaseAppHost.Container.Resolve<EventServices>();
        
        // Act
        var response = service.Post(request);
        
        // Assert
        eventManagerMock.Verify();
        requestMock.Verify();
        responseMock.VerifySet(x => x.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created, Times.Once);

        Assert.That(response, Is.Not.Null);
        ......
    }

I hope it is useful to you.
